# How to set stdout unbuffered on a per-machine basis?

Tags: python, stdout, popen, buffering, unbuffered

I ran into a case in which my machine buffered stdout, but a coworker's machine did NOT buffer stdout for the exact same code. We're running nearly identical environments (we're both using the same virtual machine image in VMware Player, but he on a Mac, and I on a PC). The code uses Popen() to execute one python script from another, and the executed script buffers stdout on my machine, but not his.

I know of these ways to control python's buffering of stdout: [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)

But neither machine had the PYTHONUNBUFFERRED environment variable set, and none of the programmatic means for unbuffering stdout were employed in any of the code.

Incidentally, adding "-u" to the Popen() call caused stdout to be unbuffered on my machine, but did not change the behavior on his.

**Taking into account that preamble, what other things might cause stdout to be buffered on one machine and unbuffered on another, for otherwise identical code?**

This might be esoteric, but it's important that I be able to give a thorough explanation, and I've run out of ideas for search strings.

EDIT: The initial program can be invoked from either the command-line or a desktop link (which issues a bash command). The VM is running Ubuntu Linux. I will try to post a simple code example, but that may take some time.

Thinking about invocation, I just realized that I usually launch from the command line and he usually launches from the desktop shortcut, which might be the critical difference. But I still don't know why...

Here is some code that demonstrates what I'm doing (mostly; there's much more to it, but it's hard for me to know what's relevant).

```
process = Popen(['python', '-u', 'some_script.py'], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
char = ''
while char != '\n' and len(read) > 0: 
    read, write, exception = select([stdout],[],[],0)          
    if read is not None and len(read) > 0:
        char = stdout.readline(1)
        output_buffer += char
#end while

if char == '\n':
    print output_buffer
    output_buffer = ''
```

The invoking script calls Popen, and then does a non-blocking buffered read, by selecting on stdout to read a character until it gets a \n or there's nothing to read.

The invoked script basically just prints a line of text using "print" (not reproduced here).

Comment: What OS is running in the virtual machine? How is program invoked? (From a command shell, from the window manager, over ssh?)

Comment: It would help if you could reproduce this with the smallest possible program that demonstrates the errori (5 lines in the invoking program, 5 lines in the invoked program should do it.) This would help others reproduce your issue, and might help you isolate the problem. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've updated my answer. I'll try to add a code snippet, but that might take a while.